# How can I speed-up compiling widgetset?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

When I create custom components in Vaadin , I noticed that every changes need to re-compile widgetset. That takes about 3 mins per compile for me . It gives me so annoying and consumes times. Has there anyways to speed-up or to skip recompiling widgetset ? Thanks for your suggestions !

Comment: as already mentioned in your other question: have you tried superdevmode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to speed up widget development in Vaadin:

1. Speed up the GWT compilation by using draft compilation and/or collapsing all permutations. Vaadin 7.2 collapses all permutations by default.
2. Use development mode. This is not anymore working in modern browsers because development mode plugins for browsers use internal APIs and those APIs don't exist anymore. IE still works.
3. Use SuperDevMode. This is THE way to do widget development in Vaadin (and GWT) nowadays. In SuperDevMode the widgetset is compiled very fast in browser when you want to see changes.

Depending on which tools you use (Vaadin Eclipse plugin, Maven, Gradle, sbt, ..) they provide ways to enabled/configure these things.